# Android: How to upload photo from ImageView?

Tags: android, image, upload

[image]

Hi guys, how can I upload the image to my filemanager on my webhost when I click the button `rent`?  As of now I don't start on anything because I tried to upload it the way I upload from gallery and It didnt work. Can you help me guys? As of now I cleaned my code and this is it

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    HashMap postData = new HashMap();

    postData.put("txtCarModel", tvCarModel.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCarType", tvCarType.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCapacity", tvCapacity.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtPlateNumber", tvPlateNumber.getText().toString());
    postData.put("image", toString());
    postData.put("txtFuelType", tvFuelType.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtOwner", tvPoster.getText().toString());


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etResDate.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert reservation date.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    postData.put("txtResDate", etResDate.getText().toString());

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etResTime.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert reservation time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    postData.put("txtResTime", etResTime.getText().toString());

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etResLocation.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert pickup location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    postData.put("txtResLocation", etResLocation.getText().toString());


    postData.put("txtRenter",  pref.getString("username","").toString());


    PostResponseAsyncTask taskPost = new PostResponseAsyncTask(DetailActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            if (s.contains("New records created successfully")) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Wait for owners approval", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, RenterTabs.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    taskPost.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/rent.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private void selectImage() {

```
    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CustomerRegistration.this);

    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        }

    });

    builder.show();

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());

            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                    f = temp;

                    break;

                }

            }

            try {

                Bitmap bitmap;

                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                // Rorate to portraite
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                bitmap = Bitmap
                        .createBitmap(bitmap,0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                                bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                // End rotrate to portait
            //set Image view        
                img_user_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




                String path = android.os.Environment

                .getExternalStorageDirectory()

                + File.separator

                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";

                f.delete();

                OutputStream outFile = null;

                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                try {

                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);

                    outFile.flush();

                    outFile.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                    null, null, null);

            c.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

            c.close();

            Bitmap bitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            // Rorate to portraite
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(picturePath));
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


            //set Image view        
            img_user_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        }

    }

}
```

// *****Just call method  selectImage() ******
img_user_photo //Image view

Comment: Hi sir, sorry for late reply I was at school the whole time. Can this code be used for uploading at `http://carkila.esy.es/uploadRent/id.jpg`? Thanks sir